# Difference in outputs between C# and java

Tags: c#, java

I am trying to write a Java equivalent for a function in C#. The code follows.

In C#:

```
byte[] a = new byte[sizeof(Int32)];
readBytes(fStream, a, 0, sizeof(Int32)); //fstream is System.IO.Filestream
int answer = BitConverter.ToInt32(a, 0);
```

In Java:

```
InputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
byte[] a = new byte[4];
readBytes(in, a, 0, 4);
int answer = byteArrayToInt(a);
```

Both Java and C#:

```
int readBytes(Stream stream, byte[] storageBuffer, int offset, int requiredCount)
        {
            int totalBytesRead = 0;
            while (totalBytesRead < requiredCount)
            {
                int bytesRead = stream.Read(
                                storageBuffer,
                                offset + totalBytesRead,
                                requiredCount - totalBytesRead);
                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    break; // while
                }

                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            }

            return totalBytesRead;
        }
```

Output:

```
In C#: answer = 192  (Correct)  
In JAVA: answer = -1073741824
```

There is a difference in the two.I am reading from a file input stream which is encoded and parsing the first four bytes. The C# code seems to produce 192 which is the correct answer while Java produces -1073741824 which is the wrong answer.  Why and how ?

**EDIT**

Here is my byteArrayToInt

```
public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b, int offset) {
        int value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            int shift = (4 - 1 - i) * 8;
            value += (b[i + offset] & 0x000000FF) << shift;
        }
        return value;
    }
```

**SOLUTION** 
The right solution for byteArrayToInt

```
public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b) 
    {
        long value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
        {
           value += (b[i] & 0xff) << (8 * i);
        }
        return (int) value;
    }
```

This gives the right output

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In java bytes are signed, so your  -64 in java byte is binary equivalent to 192 in c# byte (192 == 256 - 64).

The problem is probaby in `byteArrayToInt()` where you assume it's unsigned during the conversion.

A simple

```
 `b & 0x000000FF`
```

might help in that case.

Comment: I ve edited to include my byteArrayToInt - is this right ? What am I missing

Comment: @Vrashabh you're not missing anything. it returns `192` for byte array `{0, 0, 0, -64}` and `offset == 0`

Comment: Sorry another edit . Here are my outputs . 
C#: Before bit conversion a = {192,0,0,0} and after conversion a=192
Java: Before bit conversion a = {-64,0,0,0} and after a = -1073741824

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track. Changed my byteArrayToInt (see edit)

Answer (score 2):

Java's byte object is signed as soulcheck wrote. The binary value for 192 on an unsigned 8 bit integer would be `11000000`.

If you are reading this value with a signed format, a leading 1 will indicate a negative. This means `11000000` becomes `negative 01000000`, which is -64.